# Restar Tiempo en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como le resto las horas que quedan a un evento:

Ejemplo a las 3 PM que serian las 15 Horas debo ir al Gymnasio la tengo la hora que debo ir en este formato:

```
'2021-03-02 10:00:00'
```

Cuantas horas me quedan si actualmente tengo '2021-02-28 10:00:00' tengo este Script pero no me sale como quiero:

```
    DECLARE @tiemporeal int

SELECT TOP 1 [ActionTime] FROM [PS_GameLog].[dbo].[Gym])

SET @tiemporeal =(SELECT TOP 1  (1-(
        DATEPART(SECOND, [ActionTime]) + 
               1 * DATEPART(MINUTE, [ActionTime]) + 
                3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, [ActionTime] ) 
        )) AS Resta_1 
        --,
        --(SUM(
        --DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,cast(Duracion AS DATETIME))
    --)))) AS Resta_2
    FROM [PS_GameLog].[dbo].[Gym])

SELECT (CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, @tiemporeal, 0) AS TIME))as Restante
```

La quiero en este formato: '71:59:59' alguna idea? de como obtener el formato y la resta?
Deberia ser cuenta regresiva pero no me sale ejemplo

```
'71:59:59'
'71:59:58'
'71:59:57'
'71:59:56'
```

Asi hasta llegar a cero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de la idea que tienes dos fechas y quieres mostrar el tiempo que *falta* en una cadena con formato `'hh:mm:ss'`, puedes valerte de

- Aritmética de fechas para determinar los segundos que *faltan* entre ambas fechas
- Cocientes y residuos de la división entera para determinar a cuantas horas, minutos y segundos equivale esa cantidad de segundos

Para *ensamblar* una cadena que contenga esta información de horas, minutos y segundos en el formato deseado.

La idea básica, paso a paso, está expresada en el siguiente script:

```
declare @FechaExpira datetime = '20210302 10:00:00';
declare @FechaActual datetime = '20210228 14:21:18';
declare @hours int, @minutes int, @seconds int;
declare @falta varchar(20);

select @seconds = datediff(second, @FechaActual, @FechaExpira);

set @hours = @seconds / 3600;
set @seconds = @seconds % 3600;

set @minutes = @seconds / 60;
set @seconds = @seconds % 60;

set @falta = format(@hours, '00') + ':' + format(@minutes, '00') + ':' + format(@seconds, '00');

print @falta;
```

Que produce el resultado:

```
43:38:42
```

Que, por supuesto, se puede resumir en una pequeña consulta que haga todo el trabajo a la vez, por ejemplo:

```sql
declare @FechaExpira datetime = '20210302 10:00:00';
declare @FechaActual datetime = '20210228 14:21:18';


select   format(segundos / 3600, '00') + ':' 
       + format(segundos % 3600 / 60, '00') + ':' 
       + format(segundos % 60, '00') falta
  from (select datediff(second, @FechaActual, @FechaExpira) as segundos) q1
```

Si tienes la información en una tabla y quieres saber cuanto tiempo falta, desde la hora actual, la sentencia sería algo como:

```
select   format(segundos / 3600, '00') + ':' 
       + format(segundos % 3600 / 60, '00') + ':' 
       + format(segundos % 60, '00') falta
  from (select top 1 datediff(second, getdate(), Actiontime) as segundos from Gym) q1
```

## Edición

Dado que el AP utiliza una versión antigua de SQL Server, no hay soporte para la función format, por lo que cambiaré el código en la última sentencia para ejemplificar como puede hacerse con esta versión:

```
select   right('00' + cast(segundos / 3600 as varchar), 3) + ':' 
       + right('00' + cast(segundos % 3600 / 60 as varchar), 2) + ':' 
       + right('00' + cast(segundos % 60 as varchar), 2) falta
  from (select top 1 datediff(second, getdate(), Actiontime) as segundos from Gym) q1
```

He dejado el número de horas con una longitud de 3, como precaución, ya que la solución anterior mostraría todos los dígitos significativos si son más que 2, mientras que esta *cortaría* la cadena mostrando solo los últimos 3 dígitos para cualquier número mayor de 999 horas.

Comment: bro me sale este error uso sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 14
'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Juan edité la respuesta para mostrar como puedes hacerlo en versiones antiguas de SQL Server.

Comment: Bro te explico como dice la pregunta arriba o mejor aun como en un juego, en un lado tengo una persona que mata un monstruo que muere a las 15:00:00 horas ósea 3:00:00 PM y el mismo monstruo revivira en 4 horas PREGUNTA ¿Cuanto tiempo revivira el monstruo si el usuario que visita la web tiene las 03:30:45?

Comment: debería ir marcando desde las 03:30:45 hasta las 07:00:00 los segundos en retroceso en ese momento exacto el usuario debería tener exactamente marcado, 03:30:15 que falta para que reviva cuando el visitante tenga las 04:22:05 debería decir falta 02:38:55 para revivir por ende creo que la repuesta mas cercana ¿no seria la primera opción?

Comment: Y quedo el dia por fuera si el tiempo supero las 24 horas 2 dias serian 48 horas 3 dias 72 horas no se sumaria la diferencia?

Comment: @Juan, mi respuesta tiene todo lo que necesitas para hacer lo que describes. La idea es que te esfuerces por comprender como funciona y adaptar el código a tus condiciones particulares. Por cierto, los cálculos que pones de ejemplo son erróneos, si un usuario tiene las 03:30:45, faltan solo 03:29:15 para las 07:00:00. Si son las 04:22:05, lo que falta son 02:37:55.

Comment: hermano si eso trate de hacer de hecho pero no termino de caer que significa esto (%) en estas lineas segundos % 3600 / 60 as varchar no entendi el simbolo de % que funcion es que hace

Comment: y la que mes es mas funcional es la primera que indica dos fechas ah pero una duda cuando el contador llega a 0 que pasa? se queda en cero?

Comment: Gracias ya vi que si estaba bien tenias razon pero use la segunda consulta

Comment: el operador [`%` (módulo)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) te devuelve el residuo de una división entera.